# Empty value when iterating a dictionary with .iteritems() method

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, iterator

I am having some weird trouble with dictionaries, I am trying to iterate pairs from a dictionary to pass to another function. The loop for the iterator though for some reason always returns empty values.

Here is the code:

```
  def LinktoCentral(self, linkmethod):
    if linkmethod == 'sim':
        linkworker = Linker.SimilarityLinker()
        matchlist = []

        for k,v in self.ToBeMatchedTable.iteritems():

            matchlist.append(k, linkworker.GetBestMatch(v, self.CentralDataTable.items()))
```

Now if I insert a print line above the for loop:

```
matchlist = []
print self.ToBeMatchedTable.items()        
for k,v in self.ToBeMatchedTable.iteritems():

            matchlist.append(k, linkworker.GetBestMatch(v, self.CentralDataTable.items()))
```

I get the data that is supposed to be in the dictionary printed out. The values of the dictionary are list objects. An example tuple I get from the dictionary when printing just above the for loop:

```
>>> (1, ['AARP/United Health Care', '8002277789', 'PO Box 740819', 'Atlanta', 'GA','30374-0819', 'Paper', '3676'])
```

However, the for loop gives empty lists to the linkworker.GetBestMatch method. If I put a print line just below the for loop, here is what I get:

Code:

```
matchlist = []

        for k,v in self.ToBeMatchedTable.iteritems():
            print self.ToBeMatchedTable.items()
            matchlist.append(k, linkworker.GetBestMatch(v, self.CentralDataTable.items()))

            ## Place holder for line to send match list to display window
        return matchlist
```

Result of first iteration:

```
>>> (0, ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''])
```

I literally have no idea whats going on, there is nothing else going on while this loop is executed. Any stupid mistakes I made?

Comment: how is self.ToBeMatchedTable being populated?  Also, .iteritems() is now deprecated and should be replaced with simply .items()  e.g. for k,v in d.items():pass

Comment: Can you provide a complete example for this?

Comment: @bcollins Not deprecated - just isn't required in Python 3.x - it remains completely valid in 2.x where switching it to `items()` is quite different than the Python 3.x version

Comment: self.ToBeMatchedTable is populated by iterating through a CSV file, I am sure there is no syntax errors but I will have to go through my code to confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume the following:

```
d = {1: [1,2,3,4,54,6,7,8]}

print d.items()

for k,v in d.iteritems():
    print k, v

Output:
[(1, [1, 2, 3, 4, 54, 6, 7, 8])]
1 [1, 2, 3, 4, 54, 6, 7, 8]
```

Your `self.ToBeMatchedTable` has more than `one pair` of key and value
Usually `Python dictionaries` are `unordered` and when you try to access it, 
it works in a random manner

In your case:

There is a key value pair like `(0, ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''])`, so the second time, you have got this !

There seems to be problem in your code:

`matchlist.append(k, linkworker.GetBestMatch(v, self.CentralDataTable.items()))`

I have simulated something similar to the above line

```
>>> l = []
>>> 
>>> l.append(1, 2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: append() takes exactly one argument (2 given)
```

Try commenting or modifying your `matchlist.append(...)` line to:

`matchlist.append((k, linkworker.GetBestMatch(v, self.CentralDataTable.items())))`

Comment: Awesome, thanks! That was the problem, there actually was a bunch of empty sets, everytime I ran it and it actually go to the append line it would throw the exception but it would be buried under exceptions  printed to the command line for the GetBestMatch method not liking empty values for "v".